# Does the binomial theorem hold for a ring without unity?

Tags: ring-theory, binomial-theorem

I'm reading Theorem 8.4 and its proof from textbook Analysis I by Amann/Escher.

> [image]
>
> [image]

From this Wikipedia [page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Binomial_theorem#/The_binomial_theorem_in_abstract_algebra), I got

> [image]

From this Wikipedia [page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Semiring#/Definition), **semiring** mentioned above is defined to have a **multiplicative identity**.

> [image]

---

So both my textbook and Wikipedia assert that the binomial theorem holds for a ring with unity. On the other hand, I do not see that the proof in my textbook utilizes this property.

My question:

> Does the binomial theorem hold for a ring **without** unity?

Comment: Yes, it clearly still holds, the formula is just a matter of counting the terms when you develop the product.

Comment: Unity or not, we always have the satndard action of $\Bbb Z$ on $R$ ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen you meant the group $\mathbb Z$ acts from the left on $R$?

Comment: on the left and the right... same thing. Every abelian group has that action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right-hand side of the equation
$$(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk a^k b^{n-k}$$
is not well defined in a ring without unity because $a^0$ and $b^0$ are not defined. You can claim instead that
$$(a+b)^n = a^n + b^n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom nk a^k b^{n-k}$$
which can be obtained either by the same proof, or by simply expanding the product and counting the terms as @Captain Lama suggested.

Comment: You are so great and totally correct. My textbooks wrote this in the previous chapter: *For a further use of a recursive definition consider a nonempty set $X$ and an associative operation $\otimes$ on $X$ with identity element $e$. For $a \in X$ define $$a^{0} :=e, \quad a^{n+1} :=a^{n} \otimes a, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$$*.

Comment: I'm still awed by your great observation ;)

Comment: Thank you, but I wouldn't say great. Closer to trivial. The "flaw" was just a matter of notation, nothing more; the binomial theorem still holds.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all of the computations still hold.

No identity is ever mentioned. You simply have a sum of finite products of $a$ and $b$ and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES.

All ring without unity can be canonically embedded into a ring containing unity (Dorroh extension).  Let $A$ be a ring without unity. Consider the product ring $A\times \mathbb Z $ of elements $(x,m)\in A\times \mathbb Z $. The function $$f(x)=(x,0)$$ is an homomorphism injective of $A$ into $A\times \mathbb Z $ and this ring have the unity $(0,1)$ where $0\in A$ and $1\in \mathbb Z $.

Comment: Nice approach. The Dorroh extension is not the product ring though - there $(0,1)$ does not act as a unity. You have to modify the multiplication to $(x,m)(y,n) := (xy+my+nx,mn)$ for it to work.